# on hover Action buttons on magento product grid not showing after adding infinite ajax scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, magento

I am using ultimo theme in my Magento instances, and installed [rapidcommerce infinite ajax scroll extension](http://www.rapidcommerce.eu/en/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/Ajaxscroll.2.0.zip). after installing page scroll work perfectly but, action buttons on hover are not coming on next page products.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php if ($useIas): ?>
jQuery.ias({
delay:600,
container : '.product-columns-3',
<?php if ($productListMode == 'grid'): ?>
    item: '.products-grid',
<?php else: ?>
    item: '.products-list',
<?php endif; ?>
pagination: '.toolbar .pager',
next: '.next',
loader: '<img src="<?php echo($this->getSkinUrl('images/ajaxscroll/loader.gif')); ?>" /> <?php echo __('Loading more products, please be patient...'); ?>',
<?php if($this->getGoogleAnalyticsEnabled()): ?>
onPageChange: function(pageNum, pageUrl, scrollOffset) {
    // This will track a pageview every time the user scrolls up or down the screen to a different page.
    path = jQuery('<a/>').attr('href',pageUrl)[0].pathname.replace(/^[^\/]/,'/');
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', path]);
},
<?php endif; ?>
triggerPageThreshold: <?php echo $this->getIasTriggerpagethreshold(); ?>,
thresholdMargin: <?php echo $this->getIasThresholdmargin(); ?>,
trigger: '<?php echo __('Load more items'); ?>',
history: <?php echo ($this->getIasHistory()) ? 'true' : 'false'; ?>
});
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ($useUitotop): ?>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery().UItoTop({ easingType: 'easeOutQuart' });       
});
<?php endif; ?>
</script>
```

Please help guys.

I have tried copying templete files into theme folder, but no luck :(

Comment: Have you checked your browser console? Do you get any errors?

Comment: post reference link or your html/js code here.

Comment: No errors on console. products loads perfectly but no popup on hover over them.

Comment: js file : https://github.com/webcreate/infinite-ajax-scroll